# Robot Framework Run as different User

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, browser, automation, robotframework

I've been currently studying about Web Automation using Robot Framework. I want to start a chrome browser with Run as different user. Is there any way to start a new chrome session with the option 'Run as different user' in Robot Framework?

Comment: You have to create a google profile and pass it to the Open Browser keyword I think.